# Django Rest Framework: how to get the current superuser in serialize?

Tags: python, django, superuser

CreateApiView :

```
class CreateEmployeeApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
# authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, ]
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
queryset = Employee.objects.all()
serializer_class = CreateEmployeeApiSerializer

     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     return super(CreateEmployeeApiView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and serializer :

```
class CreateEmployeeApiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username', required=True)
email = serializers.EmailField(source='user.email', required=True)
password = serializers.CharField(source='user.password',
                                 style={'input_type': 'password', 'placeholder': 'Password'},
                                 write_only=True, required=True)

     class Meta:
         model = Employee
         fields = (
             'username',
             'email',
             'password',
             'is_delete',
             'first_name',
             'last_name',
             'father_name',
             'birth',
             'avatar',
             'status',
         )

     def to_representation(self, instance):
         data = super(CreateEmployeeApiSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
         status = instance.status
         data['status'] = Employee.USER_ROLE[status - 1][1]
         data['author'] = instance.author.username
         data['user'] = instance.user.username
         return data

     def create(self, validated_data):
         # Create new user
         print(validated_data)
         user = User.objects.create(username=validated_data['user']['username'],
                               email=validated_data['user']['email'])
         user.set_password(validated_data['user']['password'])
         user.save()

         # Create employee
         # super_user = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
         employee = Employee(user=user)
         employee.is_delete = validated_data['is_delete']
         employee.first_name = validated_data['first_name']
         employee.last_name = validated_data['last_name']
         employee.first_name = validated_data['first_name']
         employee.father_name = validated_data['father_name']
         employee.birth = validated_data['birth']
         employee.avatar = validated_data['avatar']
         employee.status = validated_data['status']
         employee.author = user
         employee.save()
         return employee
```

I need a superuser, not a simple user. When employee is created, the employee.author field must be assigned by the logged in user (i.e. the current superuser). How should I do it? I hope you understood me correctly!

Comment: What do you wan to do if the currently logged in user isn't a superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view class, you can get the current user with `request.user`. You will need to pass this into your serializer in order to set the `author`.

Answer (score 3):

You should restrict this view to only superusers. Create custom permission class as below:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class IsSuperUser(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to superusers.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_superuser)
```

And in your view:

```
permission_classes = (IsSuperUser,)
```

Read more about [permissions in DRF.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)